# RxJava testing : how to wait for all background tasks to complete

Tags: java, spring-boot, rx-java, spring-cloud

TLDR : I have background processing going on in RxJava Observables, I am in integration tests, I would like to be able to independently wait for that processing to finish to make sure that background processing started from one test does not interfere with another test.

---

Simplified, I hava  a `@RequestMapping` method that does the following :

- insert data in database
- launch an asynchronous processing of that data (http calls via Feign, db updates)
- returns nothing (`HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT`)

This asynchronous processing was previously done with a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. We're going to transition to RxJava and would like to remove this ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and do the background processing with RxJava.

So quite naively for the moment I tried to do that instead:

```
Observable
    .defer(() -> Observable.just(call to long blocking method) 
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe();
```

The end goal is of course to, one step at a time, go down into "call to long blocking method" and use Observable all the way.

Now before that I would like to make my integration tests work first. I am testing this by doing a RestTemplate call to the mapping. As most of the work is asynchronous my call returns really fast. Now I would like to find a way to wait for the asynchronous processing to finish (to make sure it does not conflict with another test).

Before RxJava I would just count the tasks in the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and wait till it would reach 0.

How can I do that with RxJava ?

---

What I tried :

- I tried to make all my Schedulers immediate with an RxJavaSchedulersHook : this cause some sort of blocking somewhere, code execution stops just before my Feign calls (Feign uses RxJava under the hood)
- I tried to count the tasks with an Rx RxJavaObservableExecutionHook : I tried retaining the subscriptions, and removing them when isSubcribed =  false, but this didn't work at all (lots of subscribers, the count never goes down)
- I tried to put an observeOn(immediate()) in the real production code. This seems to work, and I could inject the right scheduler for runtime/test phases, but I am not really keen on putting code just for testing purposes in my real production code.

I'm probably terribly wrong, or overcomplicating thing, so don't hesitate to correct my reasonning !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few month later in the game : my advice is simply "don't do that". `RxJava` is not really suited to this kind of job. Without going too much in detail having lots of "loose" Observable running in the background is not appropriate : depending on the volume of your requests you can easily fall into queue and memory issues, and more importantly what happens with all the scheduled and running tasks if the webserver crashes ? How do you restart that ?

Spring offers other better alternatives imho : [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/), [Spring Cloud Task](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/), messaging with [Spring Cloud Stream](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/), so don't do as I did and just use the right tool for the right job.

Now If you really want to go the bad route :

- Either return an SseEmmitter and consume only the first event from the SSE in the consumer service, and consume all events in your tests
- Either create an RxJava `lift` operator that wraps (in the `call` method) the Subscriber in a parent Subscriber that has a `waitForCompletion` method. How you do the waiting is up to you (with a `CountDownLatch` for example). That subscriber would be added to a synchronized list (and removed from it once completed), and in your tests you could just iterate over the list and call `waitForCompletion` on each item of the list. It's not that complicated and I got it to work, but please, dont do that !

Answer (score 6):

How to you return `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public HttpStatus home() {
    Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(longMethod())
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .subscribe();
    return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
}
```

In this form, you can't know when the `longMethod` is finished.

If you wants to know when all async jobs are completed, you can return `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` when all jobs are completed, using Spring `DefferedResult` or using a `TestSubscriber`

**PS:** you can use `Observable.fromCallable(() -> longMethod());` instead of `Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(longMethod());` if you want

#### Using DefferedResult

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public DeferredResult<HttpStatus> index() {
    DeferredResult<HttpStatus> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<HttpStatus>();
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> longMethod())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(value -> {}, e -> deferredResult.setErrorResult(e.getMessage()), () -> deferredResult.setResult(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT))
    return deferredResult;
}
```

Like this, if you call your method, you'll get your result only when your observable complete (so, when the `longMethod` is finished)

#### Using TestSubscriber

You'll have to inject a `TestSubscriber` and when ask him to wait/check the completion of your Observable :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public HttpStatus home() {
    Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(longMethod())
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .subscribe(subscriber); // you'll have to inject this subscriber in your test
    return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
}
```

and in your test :

```
 TestSubscriber subscriber = new TestSubscriber(); // you'll have to inject it into your controller
 // ....
 controller.home();
 subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
 subscriber.assertCompleted(); // check that no error occurred
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I didn't know about the TestSubscriber, and managed to get something pretty clean to work with it, but still, I had to change runtime code for testing purposes, and I really don't like that. Using a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor also solved an another problem that arose, so I went with Dave's answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `ExecutorServiceAdapter` to bridge from the Spring `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to the `ExecutorService` in RX, and then do the same trick as before.

Comment: This really the simplest and cleanest solution to my problem, no need to change runtime code for testing purposes. Thanks for the insight, I didn't realize the two libraries could be bridged so easily !

Comment: Hum, this worked fine until I was "full rx"... Logically the tasks are not all queued from the start and come and go as needed. So you can have 0 tasks on the ThreadPool and still be in the middle of the processing...

Comment: Maybe you should be asserting on something different then (eg the `DeferredResult`)?

Comment: Yes, I'm really thinking of returning an SseEmiter ... That way I can have clients just waiting for the first event (the fast one), and other clients (in tests for ex) waiting for all event to complete. This would be the cleanest imho. I've just switched to something else for a short while but will be updating all this asap